# Relatively new to SQL T-SQL and I need to convert a string date in MS SQL Server to show mm/dd/yyyy?

Tags: sql-server-2012, sql-server-2014, sql-server-2016

I have a string date formatted as Thursday, January 02 2020 and so far using format or convert to the various date types are not working for me.

In excel I am able to use

```
=TRIM(SUBSTITUTE(RIGHT(SUBSTITUTE(A2,",",REPT(" ",255)),255),RIGHT(A2,5),", "&RIGHT(A2,4)))*1
```

or

```
=DATE(RIGHT(A1,4),FIND(MID(A1,FIND(",",A1)+3,2)," anebarprayunulugepctovec")/2,LEFT(RIGHT(A1,7),2))
```

to convert but unable to replicate in MS SQL Server.

I am hoping that one of you experts can assist me.

Thanks in advance for your assistance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After doing a bit more digging I was helped with a solution that worked.

```
set language english;
GO
declare @date varchar(50) = 'Thursday, January 02 2020'

select convert(date, SUBSTRING(@date, charindex(',', @date) + 1, 50) , 100)
```

Just in case someone else has a similar issue.